# dontent div min-height=100% creates whitespace

Tags: html, whitespace, css

I've spent a good few hours searching for a solution to this, and to no avail.

I have a content div that I want to extend at least to the bottom of the page, but not to overshoot that when there's no text.  The relevant code is as follows:

```
#top {
 background-image: url('image.png');
 width: 798px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 margin-left:-399px;
 left:50%;
 display: block;
 height: 132px;
}

#content {
 position:absolute;
 top:132px;
 width: 798px;
 margin-left:-399px;
 left:50%;
 display: block;
 min-height:100%;
}

<body>

<div id="top"></div>
<div id="content">TEXT</div>

</body>
```

The problem is that, as you can see, the content div starts 132px down the page, after a header.  This translates into an overshoot of 132px of whitespace that I can scroll down to see.  That whitespace isn't there on longer pages where text fills it up, but on a short homepage, it is a problem.

I tried setting content div to bottom:0; but it had the opposite effect, so that the div would not extend below the initial bottom line of the screen, leaving text wandering outside the div on long pages.

Unfortunately, padding doesn't go negative, so I can't shave the 132px off that way.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the HTML and css on JSFiddle?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSFiddle, but here is the relevant code:

#top {
  background-image: url('image.png');
  width: 798px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  margin-left:-399px;
  left:50%;
  display: block;
  height: 132px;
}

#content {
  position:absolute;
  top:132px;
  width: 798px;
  margin-left:-399px;
  left:50%;
  display: block;
  min-height:100%;
}
<body>

<div id="top"></div>

<div id="content">TEXT</div>

</body>

Answer (score 0):

Add a container, set its max-height to 100%. Inside the container, set the individual max heights for top and content?

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    min-height:100%;
}
#top {
    background-image: url('image.png');
    width: 798px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    margin-left:-399px;
    left:50%;
    display: block;
    min-height:132px;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    top:132px;
    width: 798px;
    margin-left:-399px;
    left:50%;
    display: block;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="content"><p>TEXT</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: My making #content max-height:100%; it cuts off the div early.  Even theoretically speaking, wouldn't a max-height cut off the div from providing a background to any text extending beyond the original screen height?

Comment: My mistake, I meant to make it min-height.

Comment: You mean min-height: 100%; for both #content and #container?  It doesn't have any effect and produces the same result as just scrapping #container.  If I do that and additionally make #container position: relative； then it gets cut off early.

Comment: Theoretically, I would assume that #container should be min-height: 100%; and that then setting #content to height:auto; should cause it to fill #container, but in practice it doesn't fill it.

Comment: will setting `height: 100%;` for the content instead of `min-height` not work?